# overflow hidden not working on Android 4.3 and below

Tags: android, html, css, android-browser, mobile-browser

I'm trying to clip a picture to be round on the page. It doesn't work on Android 4.3 build-in browser and below.

```
<div class="clipper">
  <img class="profilePicture" src="http://excample.com/picture"/>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.clipper {
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  @include transform(scale(0));
  @include transition(transform 0.3s);

  &.scaledUp {
    @include transform(scale(1));
  }
}

.profilePicture {
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

Someone said it was because on Android the overflow:hidden wouldn't work when the position is relative or absolute. I tried to fix it by wrapping the whole thing in a div and make its position absolute instead. However it didn't work.

Or is it related to any other elements' style e.g.  ?

Also filter:blur on the  doesn't seem to work on Android old version either.

Comment: Your CSS doesn't seem to be vanilla. Also, you would have to use `-webkit-filter: blur;` since you would be using a webkit browser and the tag isn't supported with it being prepended to itself.

Comment: @seanlevan yes I'm using compass styling.